# Azure Active Directory Post sign out URL

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I would like to have re-direct my users to my application web page when they sign out Azure AD/Office 365. While according to the documentation from https://greeneyeits.com/?p=520, we can edit Post-Signout Link URL there and redirect the user when they sign out Azure AD/Office 365. However, this feature is not editable any more in Azure Portal. Hence, can i have a workaround for redirecting my user to my application when they sign out Azure/Office 365? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in Azure Classic portal.

Go to Classic portal with https://manage.windowsazure.com  and login your Azure account.

Navigate to Azure Active Directory > Choose your Directory> CONFIGURE >
Customize Branding

[image]

In step 2 of Customize Branding , you will find "POST LOGOUT LINK URL":

[image]

Hope this helps.

---

**Update:**

I did a test and I came across the issue as yours. We can Customize Branding for login page, but cannot set Sign out URL for AD itself.

I paid attention to this information in the CONFIGURE Customize Branding:

> If this is configured, Azure AD will show a link to a web site of your
>   choice,after users sign out of Azure AD web applications.

This means that it is configured for Web apps in Azure AD, not AD itself. So, for now , I think we cannot customize the logout redirect URL for Azure portal and office 365 itself.

Azure had changed the configuration sections in Company Branding. I haven't found a way to achieve configuring sign out URL for AD itself.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, while i have tried this in Classic Portal and actually the redirect is not working and i'm wondering if there would be a workaround for this requirement.

Comment: Hi,@Faith ,I've updated my answer. It may not be able to customize the logout Redirect URL for Azure portal and office365 ----Azure AD itself .

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Really appreciate it.

Comment: Hi, @Faith , If this answer is helpful to you ,please mark it as answer to help more people. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If the users sign out from your app, you can include the `post_logout_redirect_uri` parameter in the URL.

E.g.

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/logout?post_logout_redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fmyapp%2F
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-openid-connect-code#send-a-sign-out-request

Comment: Thanks for your reply, while I'm wondering how would the redirect would be work for signing out Azure Portal/Office 365 ?

Comment: Well, as far as I am aware, Azure Portal defines the redirect URI like this so I'm not sure if you can override that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Really appreciate it.