# Asp.Net Core - Azure AD SignOut page Branding

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, branding, asp.net-core-3.1

I'm developing an application with Asp.Net Core 3 and I'm using the Azure Active Directory for authentication/authorization with [Microsoft.Identity.Web](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web) (now a Nuget Package)

I was able to setup the branding of almost all the login/logout pages:

[image]

But I'm not able to configure it for the Sign Out page:

[image]

Do I need to change the link in the `Shared/_LoginPartial.cshtml`?
I tried to add the `?whr=custom_domain` as it was suggested in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/customize-branding#add-your-custom-branding-to-pages) but it doesn't work:

```
<a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="AzureAD" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="SignOut" asp-route-whr="*my*domain*.it">Sign out</a>
```

Here the generated link:
[image: link_hover]

**+++ Edit +++**

This is still in rolling-out phase:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/roadmap?filters=&searchterms=50476

**+++ Edit 08/07/2020+++**
The issue (in the link above) was removed, was it resolved or was the feature deprecated?

Comment: I think it will help you out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46762970/azure-active-directory-post-sign-out-url

Comment: Hi @RafaqatAli, the problem is different. In that question, they're asking for a redirect *after* the sign out. I'm asking to setup the branding of *the* sign out page.

Comment: When you are redirected to sign out, can you see the whr parameter in the URL?

Comment: yes, I added a pic with the generated link. Furthemore, the logout URL of that "Pick an account" page has my tenant id: https://login.microsoftonline.com/0108d212-bed4[...]

Comment: Just an update, Microsoft.Identity.Web is now a NuGet package. We encourage its usage to keep your library updated and with bug fixed. [Microsoft.Identity.Web wiki](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web/wiki)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the answer visible to others, I'm adding an answer shared in question.

**12/25/2019**

This feature is currently in Rolling out status.

[image]

Reference:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/roadmap?filters=&searchterms=50476