# Customize Azure AD signout page

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, microsoft-identity-platform

I'm using Azure AD for the login in my ASP.NET Core app. The sign out link is `<a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="MicrosoftIdentity" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="SignOut">`, and after the sign out is successful it redirects me to `MicrosoftIdentity/Account/SignedOut`. How can I have it redirect to another page?

Comment: It's under the Customised Branding: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46763191/495455

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case, you could build your own `AccountController` instead of the default one in the official sample, or use a [`URL Rewriting Middleware`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/url-rewriting?view=aspnetcore-3.1) to redirect the URL you want.

Reference - [How to specify custom logout URL when using Azure AD authentication in .NET core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56740143/how-to-specify-custom-logout-url-when-using-azure-ad-authentication-in-net-core)

Comment: The AccountController was moved from ASP.NET Core to Microsoft.Identity.Web. Is this still the solution? The AccountController seems pretty useless if you can't even redirect back to your own webpages.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this in your middleware (startup/program file) to redirect back to homepage on signout:

```
builder.Services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
{
    options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
    {
        OnRedirectToIdentityProviderForSignOut = context =>
        {
            context.ProtocolMessage.PostLogoutRedirectUri = context.Request.Scheme + "://" + context.Request.Host + "/";
            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }
    };
});
```